# Image (canvas) in PDF, is generated wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html

This code allows me to generate the PDF, from an image with canvas, when I generate it in cell or reduce the revolution (width x height), the image of the table in the PDF comes out in half; how could i fix it?

PDF - A4

[Correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETER7.png)

[Not correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEtV.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function demoFromHTML() {
    var elementHTML = document.getElementById('resultados');
      html2canvas(elementHTML, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
                                                                   
          var pageHeight = 1695;                                                                                
          var pageWidth = 1250;                                                                                 
          
          for (var i = 0; i <= elementHTML.clientHeight / pageHeight; i++) {
            var srcImg = canvas;
            var sX = 0;
            var sY = pageHeight * i;
            var sWidth = pageWidth;
            var sHeight = pageHeight;
            var dX = 0;
            var dY = 0;
            var dWidth = pageWidth;
            var dHeight = pageHeight;
            window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', pageWidth);
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', pageHeight);
            var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(srcImg, sX, sY, sWidth, sHeight, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);
            var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
            var width = onePageCanvas.width;
            var height = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;
            if (i > 0) 
            pdf.addPage(593, 780); 
        
            pdf.setPage(i + 1);
            pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'JPG', 20, 40, (width * .45), (height * .45));
          }
          pdf.save('cotizador.pdf');
        }
      });
          }
</script>
```